# How to send Json data containing json array within json object using JsonObjectRequest with volley

Tags: android, jsonobjectrequest

```
    String url_save = "http://13.210.238.81:8080/freelance-api/gig/addGig";

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
    try {
        obj.put("categoryId",categoryId);
        obj.put("gigDescription",edt_describeProject.getText().toString());
        obj.put("revision",edt_revision.getText().toString());
        obj.put("gigRate",edt_rate.getText().toString());
        obj.put("expectedDuration",expected_delivery.getSelectedItem().toString());

        obj.put("gigTitle",edt_uniqueTitle.getText().toString());
        obj.put("subCategoryId",sub_Category);

        JSONArray array=new JSONArray();
        JSONObject objp=new JSONObject();
        objp.put("skillId",id);
        objp.put("skillTitle",edt_skills.getQuery().toString());
        array.put(objp);
        obj.put("gigSkills",array);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final String requestBody = obj.toString();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "params-"+obj, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("params", ""+obj);




    /*final Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("categoryId", categoryId);
    params.put("gigDescription",edt_describeProject.getText().toString());
    params.put("skillTitle",edt_skills.getQuery().toString());
    params.put("skillId",id);
    params.put("gigTitle",edt_uniqueTitle.getText().toString());
    params.put("subCategoryId",sub_Category);
    params.put("expectedDuration",expected_delivery.getSelectedItem().toString());
    params.put("revision",edt_revision.getText().toString());
    params.put("gigRate",edt_rate.getText().toString());
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "params-"+params, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Log.d("params", ""+params);*/

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,url_save,new JSONObject(requestBody), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {


        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "response-"+response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("response",""+response);

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "error"+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("VolleyError","Volley"+error);
            VolleyLog.d("JSONPost", "Error: " + error.getMessage());

            NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
            if (networkResponse != null && networkResponse.data != null) {
                Log.e("Status code", String.valueOf(networkResponse.data));
            }

            /*if (error.networkResponse == null) {
                if (error.getClass().equals(TimeoutError.class)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Failed to save. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }*/

        }
    }){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "applications/json");
            headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer"+" "+sharedPreferenceConfig.ReadToken(getString(R.string.token_preference)));
            return headers;
        }
        /*@Override
        public byte[] getBody() {
            try {
                return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
                return null;
            }

        }*/
        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        }


    };

    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Json data is looks like below want to send data to the server Using JsonObjectRequest .

```
{
    "categoryId":"3",
    "gigDescription":"test",
    "revision":"3",
    "gigRate":"20",
    "expectedDuration":"10",
    "gigTitle":"test",
    "subCategoryId":"10",
    "gigSkills":
    [
        {
            "skillId":"1",
            "skillTitle":"Javaaa"

        }
    ]

}
```

Comment: why are you converting object to string then again string to object

Comment: 1) format your question. 2) What exactly is a problem? What's wrong with that code?

Comment: com.android.volley.ClientError getting this error.

Comment: @TejasPandya changed the code-"why are you converting object to string then again string to object " still getting ClientError

Comment: post your error log

Comment: getting Status code 415

Answer (score 0):

You can check status code of volly error like this. It will tell why you are getting `com.android.volley.ClientError`.

```
NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;

   if (response != null && response.data != null) {

         switch (response.statusCode) {
            case 401:
               //Session expired or token expired
            break;
            case 400:

            break;
          }
   }
```

Comment: Change your Content-Type: headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

Comment: HTTP 415 means Unsupported media type.